# React cookies don't re-render the components with new value after a modify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have a problem with react cookies: when I go to update and remove some cookies, the value of the new cookies or the removal of cookies has no effect on the components until a refresh of the page takes effect.
I would like to avoid having to refresh the page and give the user the possibility to modify cookies. The problem is that I notice that when you go to modify them, Google Analysis for example continues to work even after deleting analytical cookies.

**How can I make sure that once I modify cookies or remove them, the components are also rendered again so that I can use the new value of cookies?**

**Thank you in advance!**

**Code explanation:**

App.js initializes cookies using the react-cookie library and switches the cookies and the functions of removing and adding cookies to the components.

In the footer you can see that cookies are modified with the functions passed previously. The code has been cut a lot of things to show only the necessary ones.

In the navbar I check if the analytical cookie is true to send the event to GA that a link has been selected. And that’s where the problem starts, and if I edit and then click on a link, he remembers the previous value and not the changed value.

**App.js:**

```
export default function App() {

  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['userCookies']);

  const [blockScroll, allowScroll] = useScrollBlock();

  AOS.init();

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => {
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
      isOpen ?  allowScroll() : blockScroll();
  }  

  const functionSetCookie = (name, boolean, options) => {
      setCookie(name, boolean, options);
  }

  const functionRemoveCookie = (name) => {
      removeCookie(name);
  }

  return (
    <main className="text-gray-400 bg-gray-900 body-font">
      <Navbar toggle={toggle} cookies={cookies}/>
      <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle}/>
      <About />
      <Timeline />
      <Projects />
      <Skills />
      <Contact  />
      <Footer cookies={cookies} functionSetCookie={functionSetCookie} functionRemoveCookie={functionRemoveCookie} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

**Footer.js:**

```
export default function Footer ({cookies, functionSetCookie, functionRemoveCookie}) {

    const [checkedAnalytics, setCheckedAnalytics] = React.useState(cookies.analyticsCookie ? true : false);

    const [necessaryConsent, setNecessaryConsent] = React.useState(cookies.necessaryCookie ? true : false);

    return (
        <FooterContainer>
            <div className='cookieBannerContainer' style={{display: showBannerCookie, opacity: opacityBannerCookie, transition: 'opacity 0.3s ease'}}>
                    <div className="bannerRightColumn">
                        <button
                            style={{transition: "0.2s ease-in-out", padding: "5px 10px", margin: "15px", marginBottom:"5px", justifyContent: "center"}}
                            onClick={() => {
                                if (!necessaryConsent) {
                                    functionSetCookie('necessaryCookie', true, {path: '/', expires: dateExpire, sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
                                    setNecessaryConsent(true);
                                }
                                if (!cookies.analyticsCookie){
                                    functionSetCookie('analyticsCookie', true, {path: '/', expires: dateExpire, sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
                                    setCheckedAnalytics(true);
                                    ReactGA.initialize("XXXXXXXXXX", {debug: true});
                                    ReactGA.pageview("pageview")
                                    console.log(cookies.analyticsCookie);
                                }
                                if (checkedAnalytics === false){
                                    setCheckedAnalytics(true);
                                }
                                setOpacityBannerCookie(0);
                                setTimeout(() =>
                                    setShowBannerCookie("none"), 300
                                )
                            }}
                            className="inline-flex text-white bg-green-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-green-600 rounded text-lg">
                            Accetta tutti i cookie
                        </button>
                        <button
                            style={{transition: "0.2s ease-in-out", padding: "5px 10px", margin: "15px", marginBottom:"5px", marginTop:"10px", justifyContent: "center"}}
                            onClick={() => {
                                if (!necessaryConsent) {
                                    functionSetCookie('necessaryCookie', true, {path: '/', expires: dateExpire, sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
                                    setNecessaryConsent(true);
                                }
                                if (checkedAnalytics) {
                                    if (!cookies.analyticsCookie) {
                                        functionSetCookie('analyticsCookie', true, {path: '/', expires: dateExpire, sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
                                        ReactGA.initialize("XXXXXXX", {debug: true});
                                        ReactGA.pageview("pageview")
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if (cookies.analyticsCookie) {
                                        functionSetCookie('analyticsCookie', false, {path: '/', expires: dateExpire, sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
                                        functionRemoveCookie('_ga');
                                        functionRemoveCookie('_gat');
                                        functionRemoveCookie('_gid');
                                    }
                                }
                                setOpacityBannerCookie(0);
                                setTimeout(() =>
                                    setShowBannerCookie("none"), 300
                                )
                            }}
                            className="ml-4 inline-flex text-gray-400 bg-gray-800 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white rounded text-lg">
                            Accetta cookie selezionati
                        </button>
                        <button
                            style={{transition: "0.2s ease-in-out", padding: "5px", margin: "15px", marginTop:"10px", justifyContent: "center", paddingLeft: "10px", paddingRight: "10px"}}
                            onClick={() => {
                                if (!necessaryConsent) {
                                    functionSetCookie('necessaryCookie', true, {path: '/', expires: dateExpire, sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
                                    setNecessaryConsent(true);
                                }
                                if (cookies.analyticsCookie) {
                                    functionSetCookie('analyticsCookie', false, {path: '/', expires: dateExpire, sameSite: 'none', secure: true});
                                    functionRemoveCookie('_ga');
                                    functionRemoveCookie('_gat');
                                    functionRemoveCookie('_gid');
                                }
                                if (checkedAnalytics) {
                                    setCheckedAnalytics(false);
                                }
                                setOpacityBannerCookie(0);
                                setTimeout(() =>
                                    setShowBannerCookie("none"), 300
                                )
                            }}
                            className="ml-4 inline-flex text-gray-400 bg-gray-800 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white rounded text-lg">
                            Accetta solo cookie necessari
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </FooterContainer>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `react-cookie` library have some bugs (that I have noted recently) to manage its own state.
You should simply go to `react-cookies` core file that's located in relative path `node_modules/react-cookie/es6/useCookies.js` and replace this following code in `useCookies` function.

```
if (isInBrowser()) {
        useLayoutEffect(function () {
            function onChange() {
                var newCookies = cookies.getAll();
                // if (shouldUpdate(dependencies || null, newCookies, previousCookiesRef.current)) {
                    setCookies(newCookies);
                // }
                previousCookiesRef.current = newCookies;
            }
            cookies.addChangeListener(onChange);
            return function () {
                cookies.removeChangeListener(onChange);
            };
        }, [cookies]);
    }
```

In this code I commented out two lines except `setCookies(newCookies);`
**Reason** behind that `shouldUpdate` function always return false. So, the `if` condition couldn't `true`. It should be pass parameter `newCookies` as an `Array` instead of `Object`.

Hope you'll understand

Comment: So basically i have to set cookies for the browser and then also set the same cookies in my manage cookies? That's right?

Comment: Yes, the thing is you should handle your state by re-rendering process

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It seems that cookies do not change when I add or delete a cookie, because nothing happens.
I added the state, useffect and I passed manageCookies to the footer, but it seems that nothing happens unfortunately.

Comment: I've removed some code and run it. it's working. Maybe ReactGA or others makes conflicts to not re-rendering. Here is the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/usecookie-sandbox-forked-r60myy

Comment: @BlowLore If again nothing happens then share code via Github or CodeSandbox. So, I'll figure out deeply and fix it.

Comment: Nothing happens unfortunately. This is the github: https://github.com/lorenzobotto/portfolioWebsite, branch "development".
Just write to me when you have finished or when you have some question, so i can put it private again. Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246671/discussion-between-blowlore-and-umar-ijaz).